# Ask for permission

Tags: android

I know in recentndroid version the app has to ask for permissions on runtime but does the permissions should  be on manifest.xml permission list?
If I need to use the gps and I have this code

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    101);
        }
        else{

            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if(location != null){

            }
            else{
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        0,
                        0, locationListener);
            }
        }
```

Is mandatory to add the permission on manifest.xml?

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It's mandatory because on lower versions of Android ( <= 5.1) is not necessary ask for permissions.

Refer to this documentation:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

> does the permissions should be on manifest.xml permission list?

Yes.

> Is mandatory to add the permission on manifest.xml?

Yes, though you only need one `<uses-permission>`, not two for the same permission.

Answer (score 0):

There permissions that you must request from the user directly.  These are considered "Dangerous" permissions. Will need check to ensure you've been granted those by the user and if not request access.

Example:

```
int permissionCheck =    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);`

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
```

Please see the following for more information.
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes
This is by far a decent security procedure for the users as this will block "bad" developers from accessing everything on users phone. 
This was designed from 6.0 marshmallow version. Before this, when downloading the application, only Play store would prompt the user with features/data the application will have access to. Now it's very strict and user is provided with reasonable control over their data.